# Calling a uninitialized variable that is a function in C t

Tags: c, initialization, function-pointers

I have the following situation:

```
int aFunction() {
    int    cc;
    double *doubleValue;
    double atod();

    *doubleValue = atod ("12.3", &cc);

}
```

As far I understand `atod` is a pointer to a function, which returns a `double`, and it seems that, when `atod` is called, it is not initialized.

Am I right? What can happen, as this code is running in production?

Comment: `double atod();` is a function prototyp of a function named atod, which takes an unspecified number of parameters and return a double. `double (*atod)();` would be a pointer to such a function.

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax for a function pointer be like (*pointername)(parameters)... As far as I can see, doubleValue is a pointer to a double variable... doble atod()... Escapes me... If this were c++ I would say that you're constructing a double named atod. I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: You will get undefined behaviour (most likely a crash) because you dereference an uninitialized pointer here : `*doubleValue = atod ("12.3", &cc);`. BTW where is `atod` defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Drop that code from production immediately.

You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer and getting undefined behavior:

```
double *doubleValue;
*doubleValue = ...
```

Anyway this:

```
double atod();
```

is a **prototype** of a function which takes an unspecified number of arguments (and might cause a linking error if it's not defined elsewhere) and returns a double. To have a function pointer you should rather write:

```
double function() {
    return 2.0;
}

int main()
{
    double (*atod)(); // Pointer to function
    atod = &function;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/xIR3UU)</kbd>

Comment: `double atod();` is a function prototype, not a function declaration and it takes an unspecified number of parameters.

Comment: @mch my bad, C++ is different in this regard. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer would look like this:

```
double (*atod)();
```

What you have is a prototype. If you put it outside your function, you'd recognise it:

```
double atod();

int aFunction() {
    int    cc;
    double *doubleValue = malloc(sizeof(double));

    *doubleValue = atod ("12.3", &cc);
}
```

The compiler/linker simply finds the `atod` function from somewhere else.

I don't why anybody would choose to do this, rather than include the proper header file.

(I'm assuming the error with the uninitialized `double *` is caused by you reducing the example.)

Answer (score 0):

There are the following problems I can see from the first glance:

1. doubleValue is a pointer. You have to allocate a memory underneath **before** you're trying to dereference it and assign atod() result into.
2. atod() should be implemented in some library (or imported from  shared library), otherwise your code will compile and **will not** link.

Answer (score 0):

What confused me was  I didn't know one could put prototypes inside the body of a function, so I, wrongly, assumed it was a pointer for a function that was never initialized. I searched and found the `atod` function defined in another library. The code is correct.

The `doubleValue` error was my mistake, in trying to simplify the problem whne presenting it to you. In reality `doubleValue` is a parameter of the `aFunction`, and is already initialized.

Thanks everybody again. You have been very quick and helpfull.